# find number of factors of n , which are greater than k.

Tags: prime-factorization

if some n and k is given , we need to find number of factors of n , which are greater than k. i.e. if n= 14, k=5, then ans should be 2, i.e. 7 and 14. I know a sqrt(n) solution , can i improve my solution ?
edit : i have a constant k and many different n.

Comment: $(1)$ do you mean "divisors" ? $(2)$ Can we assume that we know the prime factorization of $n$ ?

Comment: Essentially, you need to find the prime factorisation of $n$.

Comment: From your last sentence, should we conclude that you are not just interested in an algorithm, but one that runs quickly?

Comment: @GregMartin, yeah one that have minimum time complexity

Comment: @Peter, i know an algorithm to find prime factorization for multiple queries in log(n) , so you can share a solution assuming that  the prime factorization of n is already known.

Comment: I do not think that we have in general a better way than just check the divisors. This will usually however be much faster than the sqrt-approach.

Comment: Is it feasible to compute $\gcd(n,k!)$ first? (Might be useful if you are interested in the same small $k$ but many different $n$)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen well, i have a constant k and many different n ,  but k can be 10^5 in my case.

Comment: If your $n$ allow prime factorization in $O(\log n)$, your $n$ must be special in some way - knowing in which way they are special might improve the solution ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $n=\prod_{i=1}^m p_i^{a_i}$ with $a_i\in\Bbb Z_+$, then the number of all divisors of $n$ is $\prod_{i=1}^m(a_i+1)$. We need to subtract from this the number of divisors $\le k$. To this end, we enumerate these:

All variables below must be of a type capable of holding an integer in the range $0,\ldots,k$. The $k$ entries  $D[0],\ldots, D[k-1]$ of array $D$ must also be of this type.
Only $i$ and $a'$ could theoretically take larger values, if some of the given values $m$ and $a_i$ are $>k$.

1. Init: Set $D[0]\leftarrow 1$, $w\leftarrow 1$, $i\leftarrow 1$
2. Set $r\leftarrow w$, $a'\leftarrow a_i$, $k'\leftarrow \lfloor k/p_i\rfloor$, $j\leftarrow 0$
3. If $j=r$, let $a'\leftarrow a'-1$, $r\leftarrow w$ and go to step 6.
4. If $D[j]\le k'$, let $D[w]\leftarrow p_i\cdot D[j]$, $w\leftarrow w+1$.
5. Set $j\leftarrow j+1$
6. If $a'>0$ and $r<w$, go back to step 3.
7. If $i<m$, set $i\leftarrow i+1$ and go back to step 2
8. Terminate with the following result: $n$ has $w$ divisors $\le k$.